# objects contained with in delegates

Tags: c#

I've inherited an old queue system written in c#. At its core it is just a list of delegates defined like this:

```
public delegate void QueuedEventDelegate();
struct QueuedEvent
{
    public QueuedEventDelegate fn;
}

List<QueuedEvent> queuedEvents = new List<QueuedEvent>();

public void QueueFunction(QueuedEventDelegate delegate)
{
     QueuedEvent q;
     q.fn = delegate;
     queuedEvents.Add(q);
}

public void ExecuteQueue()
{
    foreach(var item in queuedEvents)
    {
         item.fn();
    }
}
```

At another part of my code I use this setup in a for loop where add my queued events for exporting materials. :

```
foreach(var material in skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMaterials)
{
     QueueFunction(()=>ExportMesh.ExportMaterial(material));
}
```

and sligthly later I call

```
ExecuteQueue();
```

The problem I'm facing is that when a delegate is executed the parameter is interpreted as a target in the debugger and do reference an object in a later iteration of the loop above. Coming from a C++ background with very basic C# experience it seems unusual to me but my guess would be that the object that the reference is pointing to as a parameter in the delegate is being edited by the upcoming iterations of the loop. I don't see why that is happening and I'm also surprised that the code compiles since the function I'm queueing doesn't match the definition of the delegate type. What am I getting wrong about the object owner ship and why is it legal to pass such a function as in the example above to a delegate like the one above?

Comment: `the function I'm queueing doesn't match the definition of the delegate type` Of course it does.  The delegate says it has no parameters and returns `void`.  Your lambda accepts no parameters and returns `void`.  Perfect match.  Why you've bothered to create a struct just to hold a delegate is beyond me though.  Just store the delegate itself in the list.

Comment: According to [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) this should not happen anymore after C# 5.0.